# Tenant to tenant migration using Outlook only imports content from previous year

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, powershell, office365

I am attempting to do a tenant to tenant migration from 2 Office365 accounts.
Microsoft 365 support has not been able to offer any help on this, even though I'm trying to escalate to a manager.

I am using the export/import method to .pst on Windows (running in Bootcamp).
For some reason the .pst file is not being fully imported. I can see the 2 accounts show very different disk usage after import.

On further investigation, I found that all emails older than 1 year (to the exact day and time of the export) are blank. They contain headers, but not content or attachments.

There is a setting to choose how much email to download, and it's set to all for both accounts.

3rd party migration tools are apparently for bulk migrations (I only need to do 2 mailboxes).
Mover.io apparently used to do this, but was bought by Microsoft and no longer works (I queried their support).

Powershell-based methods seem to be very poorly documented.

I've already posted on the tech community forum.

Does anyone have experience with this?
Any resources or forums to try?

Answer (score 0):

Disable "Cached Mode" prior to exporting your PST, this will cause Outlook to pull data directly from the Exchange server which will take a little bit longer but will give you a complete mailbox export.

In Outlook go to File > Account Settings > Select your Account > Change > Uncheck "Use Cached Exchange Mode". You will be prompted to restart Outlook after making this change.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this.
However, the export file was 12gb already, which I believe is the complete size.
Yet after import it's about 6gb.

So it appears to be the import that is failing.
Should the destination mailbox also have cached mode set to disabled before starting the import?

Comment: The .pst file exported with cached mode on, but download emails set to all, is 13.8gb.
The completed .pst using cached mode off is 13.4gb.
I'm not sure what to make of that, or how to address the import happening fully.

Comment: Just a thought: Since the mailbox uses a kind of 2-way sync process, how will it know which end has priority or authority to sync from and to? The mailbox I am attempting to import into is no longer empty, since there is a partial migration from previously.

However, I did a test deleting 2 of the empty emails in Outlook (destination mailbox) and then redoing the import. Those messages showed up again empty.

Comment: I've completed the import again using cached mode off for the destination mailbox also.
From 10/09/2019 and older mails are blank. This suggests that maybe it's not a case of cutting off at 1 year exactly, but maybe import populates most recent first and then fails at some point afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

> I found that all emails older than 1 year (to the exact day and time
> of the export) are blank. They contain headers, but not content or
> attachments.

Can these blank items be seen normally in your primary Outlook desktop client? To further confirm your issue, it is suggested check these blank email from your primary Outlook dekstop client and see if there is any difference.

Besides, I did some research about Powershell-based methods and found some information in this article, just for your reference: [How to export Office 365 mailboxes to PST using eDiscovery](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/how-to-export-office-365-mailboxes-to-pst-using-ediscovery/).

Comment: The full emails can be seen in the source account and by exploring the export file.
There are some balnk ones in the target mailbox, which means the import failed somehow. Another import from a .pst created with cached mode switched off yielded a slightly smaller (400mb out of 14gb) file, and the empty emails starting a little before 1 year ago. 

I have a session booked with a support engineer so will ask about eDiscovery.
I was already using the primary desktop client, Outlook Windows.

Comment: eDiscovery is a way to export in the cloud (which is good since it does not lock up the computer for hours), but does not handle import.

Comment: Why Microsoft does not have a tenant to tenant migration tool in the cloud is really a mystery to me. I may end up just copying emails in small batches (by month) manually within Outlook, from source to target account (via the menu 'copy to', rather than drag and drop). The header-only/blank emails can be deleted in bullk from the source account by sorting date in Outlook.

Comment: There are so many problems with this process generally. Even using the filter by date on an export does not work properly.

Comment: I should add that thus far I have spoken with 'senior engineers', but that while they know the O365 cloud portal well, they don't have experience with Azcopy (Microsoft's command line tool for migration), Powershell or much outside of the portal environment.

Comment: Engineers are also overly dependent on the Microsoft documentation, often misunderstanding requirements or lacking sufficient critical thinking. I have usually been leading them on simple points like referring to the Github documentation for clarifying functionality of Azcopy, or offering logical solutions to filtering searches in Outlook etc.

Comment: While I understand that support engineers need to have an overview skillset, there is also a major flaw in the escalation process, which can lead to things going around in circles. After many hours of engineer time (and 50+ hours of my time)  I can simply say that it is a very inefficient process

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by manually copying (from the Outlook Windows menu - move, copy) smaller chunks of data, about 3 months of emails per chunk.

Still not sure why the export/import process failed, or why this particular configuration could not handle larger copy operations.

In case anyone else runs into similar issues, use the most basic method and try smaller batches of email for the copy operation.